# Eloquent the first where clause

Tags: php, laravel

I am wondering how Laravel implement eloquent syntax so that the first where clause can be called statically with `User::where()`

```
User::where('id', 23)->where('email', $email)->first();
```

Do they have a `public static function where()` and a `public function where()`

Comment: The answer is [magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), specifically `__callStatic()` and `__call()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `where` on an Eloquent model does involve a little bit of magic that occurs behind the scenes. Firstly, take the example of:

```
User::where(’name’, ‘Joe’)->first;
```

There’s no static `where` method that exists on the `Model` class that the `User` class extends.

What happens, is that the PHP magic method `__callStatic` is called which attempts to then call the `where` method.

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    $instance = new static;

    return call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $parameters);
}
```

As there’s no explicitly defined user function called `where`, the next magic PHP method `__call` which is defined in `Model` is executed.

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $parameters);
    }

    $query = $this->newQuery();

    return call_user_func_array([$query, $method], $parameters);
}
```

The common database related methods become accessible via:

```
$query = $this->newQuery();
```

This instantiates a new Eloquent query builder object, and it’s on this object that the `where` method runs.

So, when you use ```User::where()`` you’re actually using:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::where()
```

Take a look at the [Builder class](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) to see all of the common Eloquent methods you’re used to using, like `where()`, `get()`, `first()`, `update()`, etc.

[Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/advanced-eloquent/episodes/3) has a great in-depth (paid) video on how Eloquent works behind the scenes, which I recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Well let's find out.

When we open a model it extends `Model` so let's open that class.
In the class `Model` we find 2 "magic" methods called `__call()` and `__callStatic()`

*`__call()` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.*

*`__callStatic()` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.*

We also see in class `Model` it makes use of the class `use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as QueryBuilder;`

If we open the `Builder` class we find a method called `public function where()`

So if you call `User::where` it calls `__callStatic('where', $parameters)` from the `Model` class.

I hope this makes sense.