# Eloquent returning unpredictable result with ->where()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In one of my controllers, I have the following code:

```
$sim = 8944502311119819084;
$firstDevice = Device::where( 'sim', $sim )->first();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE sim = ?";
$secondDevice = DB::select($sql, [$sim]);

Log::debug($firstDevice);
Log::debug($secondDevice);
```

Both are returning a device with a `sim` number that doesn't match, so it's like the `where()` is being ignored.

How can this be? Is there any known explanation for this behavior? Can Eloquent somehow be using a different database connection (I mean, I'm 99% it's not, but can I rule that out altogether), or could the `Device` scope be polluted somehow?

Edit:

If I do `DB::getQueryLog()` on the first request, I get:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `devices` where `sim` = ?',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => 8944502311119819084,
    ),
    'time' => 0.76,
  ),
)
```

Edit #2;

Okay, technically my initial code example showed `$sim = '8944502311119819084';`. In my *real* situation, that sim number is coming in via the route. And it's coming in as an `int`—which makes all the difference in the world. If I switch it to `string`, it works fine. So now I've switched my example to use it as an int, which actually breaks both situations now.

I would think it's related to the max value for integers in PHP, but I've verified that I'm on a 64-bit system with 64-bit PHP, which has a max integer size of: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. That's higher than the sim:

```
Sim: 8944502311119819084
Max: 9223372036854775807
```

Is there some other reason that an integer that high wouldn't be supported by MySql or something?

Comment: use `->first();` istead `->get();` nad you must be get similar result

Comment: You can find a response. Hope it helps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211659/eloquent-the-first-where-clause)

Comment: If I try it with `->get()` I get a whole list of devices, among which is the correct one.

Comment: @Cosmin What do you mean?

Comment: I've tried to replicate your issue with your provided code but it's returning the correct record for me.

Comment: Can you post your model & migration?

Comment: What type of column is `sim`? `bigint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing this depends on the way your `sim` is stored, take a look at this:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Taking into account signed or unsigned columns (I assume yours is signed which is the default), you need your column to be `BIGINT`,  resulting in `2^63 -1` As the largest integer.

But really it might be just simpler to do `where('sim', (string) $sim)`